# Why doesn't this swap the two nodes?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to solve a question from leetcode - deleting a node from a BST.  We would be given the root node of a BST and a key; and we have to deleted the node with that key as the value.  We can assume that all the tree nodes have unique values.  We have to return the root node post this operation.  (question link is: https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-node-in-a-bst/description/).

I wrote the following code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

  struct TreeNode {
      int val;
      TreeNode *left;
      TreeNode *right;
      TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 };

TreeNode* findSmallest(TreeNode* root) {
        if(!root) return NULL;

        TreeNode* prev=root;
        while(root->left) {
            cout<<"Visiting: "<<root->val<<"\n";
            prev=root;
            root=root->left;
        }
        prev->left=NULL;

        cout<<"Returning: "<<root->val<<" and prev was: "<<prev->val<<"\n";
        return root;
    }

    TreeNode* deleteNode(TreeNode* root, int key) {
        if(!root) return NULL;

        if(root->val == key) {
            //This is the node to be deleted
            TreeNode* smallestOnRight = findSmallest(root->right);

            //the lines below do not actually change the root node - why?
            if(smallestOnRight) smallestOnRight->left=root->left;
            if(smallestOnRight) smallestOnRight->right=root->right;
            root=smallestOnRight;

            return root;
        }

        if(root->val>key)
            deleteNode(root->left, key);
        if(root->val<key)
            deleteNode(root->right, key);

        return root;
    }

int main()
{
    TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(8);
    root->left = new TreeNode(3);
    root->left->left = new TreeNode(1);
    root->left->right = new TreeNode(6);
    root->left->right->left = new TreeNode(4);
    root->left->right->right = new TreeNode(7);

    root->right = new TreeNode(10);
    root->right->right = new TreeNode(14);
    root->right->right->left = new TreeNode(13);

    deleteNode(root, 3);

}
```

I am wondering why the lines below the comment do not actually change the root node.  So, if the original tree was like (a), then after this process, the new tree is like (b), whereas it should have been like (c):

(a): [Image (a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqkrl.png) 
(b): [Image (b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYYZG.png) 
(c): [Image (c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgALl.png)

So, basically only the `node3` should be replaced with `node4`, but unfortunately this does not happen. Why is this so?

Edit: So the input would be:

> [8,3,10,1,6,null,14,null,null,4,7,13,null] 
>   3

(Tree is traversed in level order).

Edit: Here is the cpp.sh link: http://cpp.sh/9h2z

Comment: In C++ one uses `nullptr`, not `NULL`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, yes, but I am sure it is not because of that.

Comment: Right, I wanted to let you know in case you did not.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thank you for letting me know.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AluanHaddad in C++ one can use either but `nullptr` is recommended. But nor did they remove `NULL` from C++.

Comment: @immibis interestingly it looks like it was respecified to be more stringent actually.

Comment: Please post your failure case (without links or images).

Comment: @Beta, I have updated (in case you are running on Leetcode).  I will post an ideone/cpp.sh link soon.

Comment: @Beta, I have edited the question now.

Comment: The problem is that you have three different variables named `root`, and you are getting two of them mixed up.

Comment: @Beta, thank you for your comment.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The line `oot=smallestOnRight;` *does* change the value of `root`, But the `root` whose value it changes is the one local to `deleteNode`, not the one local to `main`. (Remember that giving two variables the same value does not make them the same variable.) The next step is to give these variables different names so as to tell them apart. The step after that is to change the code so as to pass the new value back to the calling function. The step after *that* is to pass the arguments by reference, so that they *are* the same variable.

Comment: @Beta, I just modified my code according to: https://www.ideone.com/6fiThc (commented on the answer below yesterday), and it worked...  The change I had made is, whenever I call `deleteNode(root->left, key);` and `deleteNode(root->right, key);` recursively, I was not assigning the returned value... I modified it to: `root->left=deleteNode(root->left, key);` and `root->right=deleteNode(root->right, key);` respectively and then it worked.  Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, that's the "step after that". The "step after *that*", undoes those modifications and adds an ampersand in just the right place.

Comment: @Beta, got it.  Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not preserved node8 that should have been modified to point to node4.  You need to preserve the parent of the node that is being deleted and modify the linkage in there.

Comment: That is a work around, isn't it?  I am trying to 'swap' the current root (`node3`) with the new node (`node4`).  And for some reason, this swap doesn't take place.

Comment: But the parent still points to the node that is deleted.  Your statement `root=smallestOnRight;` changes `root` (node3) with `smallestOnRight` (node4) but the address of `node4` is not updated in `node8`

Comment: Well, but this code: https://www.ideone.com/6fiThc has been accepted.  It is not changing the addresses in the roots either.